# Ошибки при компиляции С++20 проекта с реализацией модуля в отдельном файле

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-studio-2019, c++20

Не удается скомпилировать С++20 проект в MSVS2019 Community при реализации модуля в отдельном файле. Если поместить реализацию в самом .cppm файле, то компиляция завершается успешно. В файле реализации модуля, как указано в документации, в первую очередь объявлено:

```
module modulename;
```

Несмотря на это, объявленный в .cppm файле класс остается в .cpp реализации модуля не определенным, вследствие чего и возникают ошибки при компиляции. В чем может быть причина такой ошибки?

Comment: Читайте https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, будет дополнением к этому источнику https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20, тем не менее исключаю возможность наличия в коде не соответствия 20 стандарту, проект прост, а его код взят из книги, проблема в самой ide

Comment: Слушайте, а не проще поместить оба файла в вопрос? я бы мог попробовать их скомпилировать у себя. Если Вам по каким то причинам неудобно показывать рабочий код - наверное, Вы можете придумать простой пример, на котором проблема компиляции воспроизводится?

Comment: @S.H. Вот ссылка на скачивание https://dropmefiles.com/O9SkF, это пример из книги Gregoire M. - Professional C++, если поместить реализацию модуля в самом .cppm файле никаких проблем нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо module пользуюсь директивой import в файле реализации модуля.